# How to use a Server Certificate from the Windows Store in Nodejs

Tags: windows, node.js, certificate, store

I am currently implementing a NodeJS server, which runs on windows machine. My requirement is to enable certificate validation for client server commnunication. Currently, I have my code as below and works great (note that all the clients are sent the server Root CA certificate).

```
var ssl_options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(options.key),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(options.cert),
    ca: null        
};

server = https.createServer(ssl_options, function (request, response) {
    // server logic
}
```

But, my requirement is to use an already existing certificate from the windows store and I am not able do it properly without extracting the private key from the certificate.

I tried using the Httpsys module and it works fine but looks like it is a pretty new module which is not yet tested properly. So, wanted to know if there is any other alternative to use the windows certificate directly in Nodejs without extracting the key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nodejs - Windows Key/Certificate store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863113/nodejs-windows-key-certificate-store)

Comment: Looks like it's definitely not a duplicate. The other question is asking "how do I put things in the windows cert store". This one is asking "How do I use a cert (from the windows cert store) with my node http server

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-certs and use it in your application or reuse it's code. The idea is pretty simple - you start your application, export certificate to ram and then use for ssl connection. Initial format conversions should not matter.

Comment: now deprecated, github note says 'use https://github.com/ukoloff/win-ca' but it's a little different

Comment: hi have you manged to find the solution? I am facing similar problem, tried win-ca but now sure how would this help?