# Nodejs - Windows Key/Certificate store

Tags: windows, node.js, certificate, store

Does anybody have any pointers as to how I could go about interacting with the Key/Certificate store using nodeJs? I specifically want to add/remove certificates and possibly keys.

Update.

So the way to go here is to use "edge". Very nice work!

https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing too much about your setup here is a stab at a 'pointer' as to how to interact.

You could try using [Nodes Child Process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) and then spawning out a process to the commandline and interact with the key/certificate store the way you would via command line.  Microsofts [certificate manager tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78byta0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) perhaps?

Rough example:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
child;

child = exec('certmgr /add /all /c myFile.ext newFile.ext', 

function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
  console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
  if (error !== null) {
    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Excellent, that would be a fairly safe bet. However, I was wondering if there was a way to do it without having to call the command line.

Comment: A quick search of `npmjs.org` doesn't look promising for a module.  There's nothing in the base program that does this.

Comment: Have you had a look through [the NPM registry](https://npmjs.org/search?q=certificate) for any packages that might help?

Answer (score 1):

I've just published [node-windows-root-certs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-windows-root-certs) which uses ffi to read the windows root certificate store, and then apply these in nodejs...  may provide some inspiration.

Example use to use Windows certificates rather than internal NodeJS certificates:

```
var windowsRootCerts = require('node-windows-root-certs');
// to read the windows root certs and patch in a single command:
windowsRootCerts.useWindowsCerts();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an npm package 'windows-certs' which uses edge and a `.csx` script to read certificates in `.pem` format

- https://github.com/jfromaniello/node-windows-certs
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-certs

This should have the required functionality, but is marked as deprecated. The successor package is indicated as.`win-ca`. However, this seems to be lacking some of the functionality of the older package:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/win-ca
- https://github.com/ukoloff/win-ca

Comment: now deprecated, github note says 'use https://github.com/ukoloff/win-ca' but it's a little different

Comment: You mean _successor_ not _predecessor_. But windows-certs did and win-ca does only _read_ and this Q asks to 'add/remove'.

Comment: Original answer was edited, apparently broken, and now I get down votes! I will re-expand.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me.

```
// https://github.com/ukoloff/win-ca#inject
const ca = require('win-ca')
ca.inject('+')
```